# QIWI API запрос истории платежей

Tags: javascript, api, qiwi

Делаю такой запрос  (JavaScript)

```
    var get = function (url){
    var XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
    var getter = new XMLHttpRequest();
    getter.open('GET', url, true);
    getter.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(getter.readyState == 4) {
    console.log(getter.responseText);
    }
  };
  getter.send();
};
```

get('https://qiwigate.ru/api?key=b1ff6ae9958e0fe14ec2dae553461a8a&method=qiwi.get.history&start=10.09.2017&finish=10.09.2017');

выдаёт ошибку: {"status":"error","message":"API ключ указан неверно"}

я правильно понимаю что { key ==  token } ???

Что делать-то ребята выручайте!

Спасибо!

Comment: Видимо, неправильно понимаете, поскольку в документации на этом самом qiwigate.ru написано, что ключ - это 30 символов A-Z 0-9, а Вы пытаетесь передать 32 символа A-F 0-9.

Comment: Да, заметил после публикации... По скрипту есть предложения? Как запрос реализовать на JS support QIWI ужас... Молчит вторые сутки.

Comment: Реализовал в 15 строк  QIWI API support мёртвый.